# making folder for different path on php

Tags: php, html

i need to create a different folder view for two folder, for example, the folder is on the : C:/photo/example and the other one is on the : C:/photostrip/example and when it clicked its the path where the folder i want it
here is the code:

```
<?php
$folderfoto = 
"photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/Prints/thumb"; //folder 
tempat gambar disimpan  
 $handlefoto = opendir($folderfoto);
$foldervideo ="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/Animated";
$handlevideo = opendir($foldervideo);
$i = 1;
 //untuk video yang ini 
/*while(false !== ($file = readdir($handlevideo) )){  
if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && pathinfo("$foldervideo/$file", 
PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "jpg"){
    $file2 = str_replace("_mp4.jpg","",$file);
    $file3 = substr($file,0);
    $file4= substr($file,6);
    $file5= substr($file,15);

    echo '<li><a href="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/animated/'.$file2.'.mp4"> 
<img 
src="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/animated/'.$file.'" 
width="300" title="" type="jpg"></a><br/></li>';  
    if(($i % 4) == 0){  
        echo '<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    }*/ 
 //untuk foto yang ini  
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handlefoto) )){  
if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && pathinfo("$folderfoto/$file", PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "jpg"){
    $file2 = str_replace("_mp4.jpg","",$file);
    $file3 = substr($file,0);
    $file4= substr($file,6);
    $file5= substr($file,15);
echo '<li><a href="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/Prints/'.$file4.'">
<img src="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/Prints/thumb/'.$file.'" width="300" title="" type="jpg"></a><br/></li>';  
    if(($i % 4) == 0){  
        echo '<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
    }


    $i++;
    if($i == 0){
        break;
    }
    }   
}  
?>
```

Comment: this will not solve your problem but makes your code more simple if you would use `scandir()` [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: You may also find it easier by using `glob()` in combination with `pathinfo()`